# 301 redirect file generator page

Tags: php, redirect, zip

I need to create a site (with PHP) which has inputs. For each line, I can paste an URL. Then, it needs to generate a 301 redirect file for each URL and needs to offer a ZIP compressed download. Can you give me some tips where to start? Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

add below line in .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 301 /test/file.zip // Example
```

i hope it's work.